# Unity3D trying to load a texture resource after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a material that is using a texture (image) located in the Resources directory under Assets. Using Resources.load works while in the editor. The texture also loads properly on a build, but I would like to replace that image after the build by placing a different image (with the same name) in the built Resources directory.

On Windows, I think that directory is buildname_Data>Resources and on Mac I'm thinking it's Contents>Resources (after opening Package Contents). This works for a text file I'm using to load some data at startup, but the process is a bit different there as I'm not using Resources.load in that case.

The problem I'm having is that just placing a new image in the (i think) proper location does not override the image that the app was built with. I'm still seeing the original image. I've been scratching my head over this for the past couple days, and the Documentation (as well as various google searches) have not yielded insight into a solution (although it's likely staring me right in the face).

```
var MyTexture : Texture = Resources.Load("colorPatch");

var wbpLineRenderer : LineRenderer = someGameObject.AddComponent(LineRenderer);
wbpLineRenderer.material = new Material (Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended"));
wbpLineRenderer.material = Resources.Load("curveLine") as Material;
wbpLineRenderer.material.mainTexture = MyTexture;
```

curveLine is a material in the Assets/Resources directory of the Editor.

colorPatch is an image file named colorPatch.png in the Assets/Resources directory of the Editor

Can someone please screw my head on straight about this? Can I actually swap an image used on a texture after build?

Comment: Why not just use both of them? If you think that will take up to much space, you might want to consider researching [texture atlasing](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/texture-atlas-tutorial.149939/).

Comment: The point is, that the Unity Built App is to serve as a 'reader' or rather a 'displayer of information' which isn't available at the time of the build. The image is to come later and be external but still be used by the built app.

Answer (score 0):

After a good breakfast and a bit more googling I have (re)discovered the solution, detailed [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/271821/loading-external-image-as-texture2d-increases-memo.html).

my implementation is as follows:

```
var textureURL : String = "file://" + Application.dataPath + "/Resources/colorPatch.png";
var www : WWW = new WWW(textureURL);
var tempTexture : Texture2D = new Texture2D(2, 2); //doesn't have to be the actual size
www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tempTexture); //image loads at 100% not 2x2 specified above

var wbpLineRenderer : LineRenderer = wellBorePath.AddComponent(LineRenderer);
wbpLineRenderer.material = new Material (Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended"));
wbpLineRenderer.material = Resources.Load("curveLine") as Material;
wbpLineRenderer.material.mainTexture = tempTexture;
```

Once the app is built, place an image named colorPatch.png in the location:

Windows - appname_Data/Resources
Mac - Contents/Resources (after opening Package Contents).

Switching out the image colorPatch.png with another image (but still titled colorPatch.png) then launching the app, displays the new image as the texture.